# duplicating library in an overlay section at link

Tags: gcc, linker, gnu, ld

In an embedded system, with a GNU toolchain, I'd like to execute code from RAM using an OVERLAY section at link, when the flash memory (where the code is located into) is unavailable.

My problem is when the C functions in the overlay (in RAM) uses functions from libraries (example: div/mod/... from libgcc). The libgcc is linked in the main code section in flash which is busy.

Is there a way to prevent cross references (and how to duplicate library code?) between such a RAM overlay and the flash memory?

Cheers!

Comment: This is pretty deep voodoo.  What sort of embedded system is this?  You can't simply use a static binary and copy it into RAM manually?  What you seem to be asking is, of course, impossible: no, you can't prevent duplication of code between a libgcc in flash and a program in RAM that cannot use the flash (well, unless you avoid use of anything from libgcc at all, which is itself mostly impossible).  Basically: your problem is probably elsewhere.  Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The target is a baremetal elf target. I'm trying to have a standalone code which is run from RAM when the flash is busy, using a single ld script. This is perhaps not possible.

Comment: Sorry, I want to duplicate lib code. Question edited. I tried to use an overlay using a single ld script since it simplifies memory allocation while keeping stacks and variables up in RAM...

Comment: I had a similar issue, but mine involved some CPU ROM code that validates binaries.  In order for the binary to *validate*, it needs to be in the same position as the boot loader that is loading it.  You may prohibit the use of 'div/mod' by not using those features.  Another way is to use '-nostdlib' and define each and every file yourself.  You can use a define to compile 'memcpy', 'memset' twice and rename them.  If you must use 'div/mod', then symbol renaming is probably the only choice.